# Night mode and brightness adjust not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: asus, ubuntu-gnome

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my asus vivobook x412da, it has amd ryzen 5 and Radeon vega graphics. The brightness adjuster and night mode are not working in it.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: It may be a bug since someone else has a similar problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270902/20-04-1-lts-resumes-to-full-brightness)

Comment: Solved this problem by reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 with the download option checked for installing third party drivers, apps etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am **ASUS TUF-17** series user having ryzen 5 processor.
and currently installed 20.04 LTS focal-fosa release in it.

So here is my solution for controlling so bright white light on your laptop, hope it'll helped out for other users too-

First of all,

Plzzz, Plzzz, Plzzz didn't do anything for your brightness ,if you have ***ASUS A15,A17 or any ASUS ROG series or gaming laptop***.

I tried all of the possible ways to do so-
Neither changing the

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

is worked,nor

> any changes in grub file config.

***This NVIDIA problem is so frustating.***

or **You will get stucked into infinity reboot** .

*The simplest way to reduce eye strain is to install **Redshift** App for linux.

**#1) Redshift**

you can, using this command-*

```
sudo apt-get install redshift

sudo apt-get install redshift-gtk

sudo apt update
```

*This app is so beautifully optimises brightness intensity automatically,You just didn't need to control brightness.*

Now, You can use different IDE's with having white background easily in late night hours.

Some More App I personally suggest you for your eye-care is-

**#2**

> Safe Eyes   ____"available in ubuntu store" .......(it'll let you make some breaks in long working hours)

**#3**

> Screen Shader .......(it is a chrome extension for more light filtering)

***That's ALL.
Now, You didn't need to worry about your Brightness***

Comment: Please do not send the same answer to different questions. When you reach sufficient reputation you can flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: OK @Ravexina , thanks for following my answers such as deeply. 
But let me clear you one thing-
This is not about reputation or all that funky badges or whatever u earn in this platform . I just spread the same answer in ~same questions because,
 there are lack of answers available to this topic .
 i had too frustated with this problem so long periods so thats why i m spreading it to everyone so that they can spread that information further too.

that badges or other things are just for kids to hanging around :) thankyou && stay safe.